# Storing a percentage in Rails + MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to use a percentage in my Rails app.  In any view, including when it is entered by the user, the format will need to be the hundreds format, `100.000`.  When it's used in calculations, it needs to be represented in the hundredths format, `1.00000`.

My migration (I'm adding the column to an existing table) has the following line:

```
add_column :worker, :cash_split, :decimal, :precision => 6, :scale => 5
```

So, as of right now, I'm storing it in the hundredths (`1.00000`) format. My basis for choosing to store it in this format is that i figure it will mean cleaner business logic (i.e. no `worker.cash_split / 100.0.to_d` code hanging around) when i need to do multiplication.

My only other thought was maybe abusing the composed_of method.  I could store the data in the hundreds (`100.000`) format as cash_split and then make an attribute accessor `cash_split_percentage` that returns `cash_split` in its 1.0000 format counterpart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first thought is the right one...don't overthink it.

You should definitely store percentage numbers in the database in hundredths format. And use that format in all of your Ruby calculations.

Percentage figures are a *display* convention. Eg the *number* 0.45 is displayed as 45%. As such, use a View helper to convert your percentage figures from their internal format (decimal numbers) to your chosen display format--a string which includes the % sign.

Comment: How would you handle percentages in forms? Users will want to enter it like 45% but it should be stored as 0.45. Nevertheless, if the user inputs another field wrong and the form is re-rendered, the percentage field sould have 45 and not 0.45. With this I want to say that a callback may not be the final solution.

Comment: you could write getters and setters for the percentage in the hundreds format. so you'll have the attribute #some_ratio and the methods #some_ration_percentage & #some_ration_percentage= which will just divide/multiply by 100 and move on.

Comment: @BishmaStornelli Completely agree. Was writing a comment here but I may as well write another answer to provide this view point.

Answer (score 0):

#### It depends.

First off, I don't think there is a right way or a wrong way. It's your app and your code, so you can do what you want, but you should do what makes the most sense for your circumstances.

As [@BishmaStornelli commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203268/storing-a-percentage-in-rails-mysql#comment22702183_8203616) in [@LarryK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203616/293280),

> How would you handle percentages in forms? Users will want to enter it like 45% but it should be stored as 0.45. Nevertheless, if the user inputs another field wrong and the form is re-rendered, the percentage field sould have 45 and not 0.45. With this I want to say that a callback may not be the final solution.

You're damned if you do and you're damned if you don't. You either clutter up your calculation code with divisions by 100, or you clutter up your Model and Views with converting from a decimal to a percentage and back again.

**I suppose the answer depends on which is more heavy in your application.**

If you are conducting lots of calculations based on this percentage then storing it as a decimal would seem like the best approach that will provide the least amount of code and the clearest, cleanest code to view and maintain.

However, if you are not conducting lots of calculations based on this percentage (maybe only a couple) then it may make more sense to not have to write a bunch of code in the Model and Views to display the decimal as a nice percentage, and just divide by 100 when you need to perform a calculation.

In our particularly case, and the reason I ended up here, we want the User to enter the value as a nice percentage, like `75%`, in the form. And we *always* want to display this value in Views, Reports, etc. as a nice clean percentage, like `75%`. And we only need to perform a calculation with this value a couple of times.

**So, it makes sense in our case to store the value as a percentage in the database. It makes saving and viewing much easier, and only incurs a "divide by 100" penalty in the couple of spots we perform a calculation on it.**

Hopefully, that helps others and provides a different viewpoint to the already well-written and accepted answer.

Thanks @BishmaStornelli for the alternative perspective!