# Mysql data type for percentage

Tags: mysql

What would be best data type in MySql to save datatypes of the following:

```
-0.46%
-10.5%
+103.1%
-88.26%
```

I am following this [link](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file)

Comment: [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Comment: please see the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656948/how-to-store-a-percentage-value